# Pass params with Link react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an index component on the `'/'` route and in that component I have a `Link`. When I click the link I do get rerouted to `/search`, but how do I pass some params with that link and get them inside the component being rendered on the `/search` route.

This is what I've tried so far:

Link inside the index component:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/search', query: this.state.status  }}>
                    Search
                </Link>
```

The route matching the `/search`

```
 <Route exact path="/search" component={Search}/>
```

The `Search` component

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        console.log("Props are: ");
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-12 text-center tweet-background">
                <h1>{this.props.query}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

But unfortunately the `props` params only have:

```
Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined}
```

Did I pass my params right inside the Link? If not, how can I achieve this?

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, think about the google search. You click `Search` and it takes you to another component with the params.

**Edit:**

For simplicity, because most of the questions were about the state of the index component, I changed the query to `query: { name: 'ryan' }`.

Comment: What does the location object look like? (`this.props.location`)

Comment: It has `hash,key,pathname,search,state`

Comment: Are one of those the prop you're passing? Is `state.search` correct on your index component?

Comment: I'm not passing any of those.

Comment: No, you're not passing them directly, but if the `Link` is correctly defined, those props will be injected and should reflect what you've defined in `Link` (`indexComponent.state.status`).

Comment: What does `indexComponent.state.status` look like? Is it an object that can be directly passed to `Link.props.to.query`?

Comment: This is the format `this.state = {
            status: 'test'}`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than replacing `query` to `search`, you can access `query`, as:

```
this.props.location.query
```

Given:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/search', query: this.state.status  }}> Search </Link>
```

Comment: Nice answear, it helped me a lot, but I have a doubt. What is the user press F5? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React-router injects `location` property which is an object with some properties including `search` which stores the query string portion of the URL so please try using:

```
this.props.location.search
```

Comment: can console.log `this.state.status`?

Comment: I'm not setting the state to anything for the Search component.

Comment: So what are you passing as `query` param in Link component? In your code - `query: this.state.status`  -  you're using `state.status` so if it's empty clicking this link will redirect to URL without query params..

Comment: Oh, thought you wanted the state of the `search` component. The state of the index component is `this.state = { status: 'test'}`

Comment: How URL in a browser look like after clicking the link and using @JonSurell solution?

Comment: The query doesn t get appended if that s what you re asking for. It s just '/search'. Anyway I want a post functionality if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same problem, replace the `query` with `search`.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/search', query: this.state.status  }}>
                    Search
                </Link>
```

would become this

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/search', search: this.state.status  }}>
                    Search
                </Link>
```